# Multi Line list items indent

Tags: css

Not sure if I'm having a stupid day or not but wondering if there is a hack around this.

When I have a multi-line list item with no list style, I get this indent as if the bullet should be there.

Anyway arond this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```